# Upgrading mysql from 4.1.22 to 5.0

Tags: mysql, linux, root

I'm trying to upgrade our company's 4.1.22 version of MySQL to 5.

I'm using

```
 sudo yum --enablerepo=centosplus upgrade mysql*
```

but keep getting an error of conflicted files with the 4.1 version.

Does that mean there really isn't any other way than uninstalling 4.1 and installing 5.0? I have read that using the yum upgrade command should work however...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This should be moved to superuser

Answer (score 0):

You need to uninstall MySQL 4.1.22 and fresh install MySQL 5. We recently migrated from MySQL 5.0 to 5.5 which required similar steps.